# Why "int i" has multiple definitions?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, header-files

I have two files as below:

*Test1.h*

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int i = 10;

#endif
```

*Test2.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Test1.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I know I can solve this by using **extern** or **const** in `Test1.h`.

But my question is that "I don't understand the error".

> error LNK2005: "int i" (?i@@3HA) already defined in Test1.obj
>   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

How can `int i` have multiple definitions?

1. The header file has include guards.
2. When I include the header file it should mean that everything gets copied in `Test2.cpp`and it should become:

*Test2.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 10

int main()
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

And header file should become irrelevant at this point after everything being included.

My other question is if I declare `int i` with `extern` in header file and include it in .cpp, then would it be an example of external linkage? Because generally I have seen external linkage between two `.c` or `.cpp` as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(software)) but if you explicitly include the file is it still regarded as `i` having external linkage?

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track looking at the effect of the `#include` directive; just don't forget that it's done **both** source files. Test1.cpp **also** has `#include "Test1.h"`, so it has **the same definition** of `i` as Test2.cpp has. That's why the linker is complaining.

Comment: The error message indicates that there is also a `Test1.obj` involved, which you failed to mention in your question. Please show the commandline you used to compile, as well as all source files involved

Comment: I think you included the header in the compile command. You probably did something like `g++ Test1.h Test2.cpp -o main`. You don't need to specify the header in the compile command.

Comment: I don't have `Test1.cpp`.

Comment: @Norman *I don't have Test1.cpp* -- So where did `Test1.obj` come from?  You must have compiled something to produce that object file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit concevably he could have created `Test1.obj` from `Test2.cpp` or some other file not shown

Comment: I really don't have it. I just double checked it. I am using Visual C++ compiler 2013.

Comment: Re: "I really don't have it." -- then there's something messed up in your project. Start a new one.

Comment: It was likely a bug in compiler. I renamed the `Test1.h` to `Test2.h` and the error is completely gone. It happened because I renamed `Test1.cpp` to `Test1.h`.

Comment: @Norman Did you perchance set up `Test1.h` in the project properties as "Item Type C/C++ compiler" instead of "Item type C/C++ header"?

Comment: @Angew: No, I didn't. I have no other clue that even after rebuilding and cleaning the project the error would still show up. Anyway, I tried the same thing on Code::Blocks with GCC compiler and it compiles perfectly fine.

Comment: @Angew: Now, it compiles fine on Visual Studio as well after setting the option that you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can int i have multiple definitions?

The file that has the definition was included in multiple translation units (cpp file). One unit was compiled into the object file `Test1.obj`. The source of the other unit is shown in your answer (`Test2.cpp`). The error is shown when you try to link the object files together.

> 1. The header file has include guards.

That prevents the contents of the file from being repeated within a single translation unit. It makes no difference to separate units.

> My other question is if I declare int i with extern in header file and include it in .cpp, then would it be an example of external linkage?

`extern` makes the linkage external explicitly. But even without `extern`, variables declared in the namespace scope have implicit external linkage by default (there are exceptions). The difference in this case is that `extern` variable declarations are not definitions unless there is an initializer.

> I can achieve external linkage without including header file i.e. with two .cpp files by making a variable extern in one .cpp and defining it in other and linker finds its definition. But if I have one header file with extern variable and include it in other .cpp does this count as external linkage?

It does not matter how the extern declaration ends up in the cpp file. Whether it was included from a header or not, it declares a variable with external linkage.

Comment: @user2078303: I can achieve external linkage without including header file i.e. with two .cpp files by making a variable `extern` in one .cpp and defining it in other and linker finds its definition. But if I have one header file with `extern` variable and include it in other `.cpp` does this count as external linkage?

Answer (score 3):

Each compilation unit (a .cpp file) produces its own set of symbols individually which are then linked together by the linker.

A header file "becomes" part of the compilation unit it is included in, which compile to an object file (.obj in Windows, .o in Unix systems)

Therefore it is like you have defined a global 'i' in each compilation unit.
The correct solution (as you know, if you have to have a global) is to declare it as "extern" in the header then have one compilation unit actually define it.

Include guards only prevent the same header being included twice in the same compilation unit, which can happen if I include  and  and one of those includes the other.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to create the executable file from two unit of translations.

Your error shows that the object have been defined in Test1.obj. Probably, your program is Test1.obj+Test2.obj, and both files include the same definition, which has external linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other *Test1.cpp* in your project that also include the *Test1.h* ?

If not, do you do any config to your compiler so it also build the *.h* files to object files ?

The reason can just be the answer of one of two questions above.

Answer (score -1):

> When I include the header file it should mean that everything gets copied in Test2.cpp and it should become:

Yes and then you do the exact same thing in Test1.cpp (which you didn't show us).

Hence, multiple definitions.

Comment: I don't have `Test1.cpp`.

Comment: @Norman: Yes, you do. Either that, or you're compiling Test1.h itself too for some reason.

Comment: I just found it It was probably a bug in Visual Studio. Earlier I renamed `Test1.cpp` to `Test1.h` and even after I "rebuild" the project several times the error was showing up. But now again I renamed the `Test1.h` to `Test2.h` and now the error is completely gone.

Comment: Light: Suppose even if I had Test1.cpp, shouldn't include guards prevent the ".h" from being included multiple times?